# Solr version supported by Solandra

Tags: solr, cassandra, solandra

Does anyone know what version of Solr that Solandra will support? Is it just the latest version? I'm most concerned with the geospatial capabilities of Solr and I would like to know if Solandra will support this.

A link would be great also. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solandra uses Solr 3.2 currently so geo is supported